# Change in how Salesforce manages Email Relay entries in refreshed / newly created sandboxes - any documentation?

Tags: email, email-relay

I have noticed that in the past, previously created / refreshed sandboxes had Email Relay entries that matched Production.

However, since the last release, I notice that newly created / refreshed sandboxes **do not** have Email Relay entries anymore. I cannot find any documentation explaining this. Is this a Salesforce refresh inconsistency here or was this made intentionally and if so, why?